# How to make the transparent custom tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar

How to make transparent custom tab bar? I set the background image is transparent image but tab bar having the black image? How to I remove the black image? Please help me. See the image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the TabBar's tint color to `clearColor`.

```
[[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Are you using Xib ? if you are using xib then set tint color or set it programitacally

Comment: Custom tab bar, separately create the file using UITabBArController.

Answer (score 1):

Try that, create an image and set as background ios5=> only:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *transparentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:transparentImage];
```